# Possible to add multiple parameters to excel import?

Tags: php, excel, laravel, laravel-excel

I have a basic form that contains an excel file upload and a select option.

The select contains a few options. I want to pass the selected option from the user with the file to my `Excel::import`

I tried passing another parameter to my import but it returns error. (has to be string, array given)

**Is this possible using Laravel excel import?**

**Controller**

```
public function create(Request $request)
{
    if($request->hasFile('file')) 
    {
        $package = $request->input('package');
        // how can I add $package to my import to insert it to my user model?
        Excel::import(new AccountsImport, $request->file('file'));

        return ['message' => 'Excel has been succesfully uploaded'];
    }
}
```

**AccountsImport**

```
class AccountsImport implements ToCollection, withHeadingRow
{

    public function collection(Collection $rows)
    {
        $rows->each(function($row, $key) {
            Account::create([
                'name'   => $row['student'],
                'email'  => $row['e_mail'],
                // Want it to be possible to add my package here
                //'package' => $package
            ]);
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe you could pass down custom data to your `AccountsImport` class?

You would have a data array as such:

```
$data = [
    'package' => $package, 
    // other data here
];
```

You would then do something like this:

```
Excel::import(new AccountsImport($data), $request->file('file'));
```

That would require some changes in your import class.

```
class AccountsImport implements ToCollection, withHeadingRow
{
    private $data; 

    public function __construct(array $data = [])
    {
        $this->data = $data; 
    }

    public function collection(Collection $rows)
    {
        $rows->each(function($row, $key) {
            Account::create(array_merge([
                'name'   => $row['student'],
                'email'  => $row['e_mail'],
                // Want it to be possible to add my package here
                //'package' => $package
            ], $this->data));
        });
    }
}
```

I took a look at Laravel Excel's API and couldn't see something that would cater for this, but this should work.